# Simple program that prints out runners, names and time

Tags: c++

I am supposed to create a program that let's the user input runners' names and times. When the user types `DONE`, the user will start to input the times of the runners, ending with `-1`.

For clarity, in the terminal, it should look like something like this:

```
Enter participants:
Kalle Svensson Glommen IK
Anna Nilsson Glommen IK
Per-Erik Jonsson Tuna OK
DONE
Times Kalle: 12.34 10.01 -1.00
Times Anna: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34 -1.00
Times Per-Erik: 10.44 -1.00
Surname First name Club: Times
==========================================
 Nilsson Anna Glommen IK: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34
 Svensson Kalle Glommen IK: 10.01 12.34
 Jonsson Per-Erik Tuna OK: 10.44
```

My code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
    
using namespace std;
    
struct Runner_Type
{
    string first_name;
    string surname;
    string club;
    string club_last;
    vector<double> time;
};

using Many_Runners_Type = vector<Runner_Type>;

void print(Runner_Type const & runner)
{
    cout << setw(9) << runner.surname << setw(10) << runner.first_name << setw(13) << runner.club << setw(3) << runner.club_last;
}

void print(Many_Runners_Type const & many_runners)
{
    for (Runner_Type const & runners : many_runners)
    {      
        print(runners);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
    
bool operator < (Runner_Type const & lhs,
                 Runner_Type const & rhs)
{
    for (int j {}; j < static_cast<int>(lhs.time.size()); ++j)
    {
        if (lhs.time.at(j) < rhs.time.at(j))
        {
            return true;
        }
          
        else if (lhs.time.at(j) > rhs.time.at(j))
        {
            return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }
}
    
// void participants ()
// {
//     Runner_Type runner;
//     Many_Runners_Type many_runners;
//     string name;
// }
    
int main()
{
    Runner_Type runner {};
    Many_Runners_Type many_runners {};
    string name {};
    double runner_time {};

    cout << "Enter participants: " << endl;
    
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> name;
    
        if (name == "DONE")
        {
            break;
        }
    
        runner.first_name = name;
    
        cin >> runner.surname >> runner.club >> runner.club_last;
        many_runners.push_back(runner);
    }
    
    for (int i {}; i < many_runners.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Times " << many_runners.at(i).first_name << ": ";
    
        while (runner_time != -1.0)
        {
            cin >> runner_time;
            runner.time.push_back(tid);
        }
    }
    
    //runner.time.pop_back();

    cout << "Surname" << setw(11) << "First name" << setw(23) << "Club: Times" << endl;
    cout << "==========================================" << endl;

    sort(begin(many_runners), end(many_runners));
    print(many_runners);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

These are the warnings I get from my compiler (observe that my program runs, but I get warnings, not errors):

```
CppO3.cpp:104:21: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<Runner_Type>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  104 |   for (int i = 1; i < many_runners.size(); ++i)
      |                   ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CppO3.cpp: In function ‘bool operator<(const Runner_Type&, const Runner_Type&)’:
CppO3.cpp:59:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   59 | }
      | ^
```

And when I run my program, this is the output I get:

```
Enter participants: 
Kalle Svensson Glommen IK
Anna Nilsson Glommen IK
Per-Erik Jonsson Tuna OK
DONE
Times Anna: 12.24 10.01 -1.00
Times Per-Erik: Surname   First name         Club: Times
==========================================
 Svensson     Kalle      Glommen IK
  Nilsson      Anna      Glommen IK
  Jonsson  Per-Erik         Tuna OK
```

Any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The warnings are self-explanatory.

The 1st warning is telling you the `for` loop is comparing a *signed* `int` to an *unsigned* `long`. Use `size_t` instead of `int`, or even `std::vector<Runner_Type>::size_type` (what `size()` actually returns). Or better, use a [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop instead.

The 2nd warning is telling you that there is a flow path in `operator<` that results in it exiting without `return`ing a value (namely, if the outer `for` loop is not entered because `lhs.time` is empty). Your final `return true;` is in the wrong place.

---

That being said, there are many other problems with your code.

The code doesn't even compile as shown, because `tid` is unknown on `runner.time.push_back(tid);`, it should be pushing `runner_time` instead.

Also, that `while` loop is wrong anyway, for two reasons:

1. This logic:

   ```cpp
   while (runner_time != -1.0)
   {
       cin >> runner_time;
       ...
   }
   ```

   should be like this instead:

   ```cpp
   while (cin >> runner_time && runner_time != -1.0)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. it is not even pushing `runner_time` into the correct `vector` to begin with.  You are pushing into the `time` vector of the last `runner` populated by the previous `while (true)` loop.  You need to push into the `time` vector of `many_runners[i]` instead (not that it matters, because `print()` is not attempting to output each runner's `time` values, anyway).

Also, your `operator<` is using bad sorting logic. Your example runners don't have the same # of times, but your operator expects them to. So you are likely to get runtime errors accessing `time.at(j)`.  Since you want to sort the runners by their fastest times, you should `sort()` their times after entering them, which will then simplify the logic needed by `operator<` as the only `time` values it will need to look at will be `time[0]` of each runner.

And lastly, your `setw()`s for setting up the output columns are inconsistent between `main()` and `print()`.

With all of that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;
    
struct Runner_Type
{
    string first_name;
    string surname;
    string club;
    string club_last;
    vector<double> time;
};

using Many_Runners_Type = vector<Runner_Type>;

void print(Runner_Type const & runner)
{
    cout << left << setw(9) << runner.surname << setw(11) << runner.first_name << setw(13) << runner.club << setw(2) << runner.club_last << ":";
    for(double runner_time: runner.time) {
        cout << " " << runner_time;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print(Many_Runners_Type const & many_runners)
{
    for (Runner_Type const & runner : many_runners)
    {      
        print(runner);
    }
}
    
bool operator < (Runner_Type const & lhs,
                 Runner_Type const & rhs)
{
    if (!lhs.time.empty()) {
        return rhs.time.empty() || lhs.time[0] < rhs.time[0];
    }
    else {
        return rhs.time.empty();
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    Runner_Type runner {};
    Many_Runners_Type many_runners {};
    string name {};
    double runner_time {};

    cout << "Enter participants: " << endl;
    
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> name;
    
        if (name == "DONE")
        {
            break;
        }
    
        runner.first_name = name;
    
        cin >> runner.surname >> runner.club >> runner.club_last;
        many_runners.push_back(runner);
    }

    for (size_t i {}; i < many_runners.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Times " << many_runners[i].first_name << ": ";
    
        while (cin >> runner_time && runner_time != -1.0)
        {
            many_runners[i].time.push_back(runner_time);
        }

        sort(begin(many_runners[i].time), end(many_runners[i].time));
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << left << setw(9) << "Surname" << setw(11) << "First name" << setw(17) << "Club" << "Times" << endl;
    cout << "==========================================" << endl;

    sort(begin(many_runners), end(many_runners));
    print(many_runners);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Clkn8o)

Comment: I fixed the warnings but it will still type out the same things like it did before, which is wrong. How do I fix this? You can see how it will look in my terminal. I showed you it in the question.

Comment: "*it will still type out the same things like it did before, which is wrong*" - wrong HOW exactly? You need to be more specific. You can see from my [example demo](https://ideone.com/6FudDS) that this code prints out what you asked for.