# How to sort doubles in a vector in order?

Tags: c++, vector

I am supposed to create a program that let's the user input runners names and times. When the user types `DONE`, the user will start to input the times of the runners, ending with `-1`.

The program should finally print all runners sorted according to the runners' individual fastest time
(the runner with the fastest time is printed first, followed by the runner with the second fastest time, ect.). Also
the runners' own times must be printed sorted where the fastest time is printed first, followed by the second fastest
time, ect. The times must be printed separated by exactly one space.

For clarity, in the terminal, it should look like something like this:

```
Enter participants:
Kalle Svensson Glommen IK
Anna Nilsson Glommen IK
Per-Erik Jonsson Tuna OK
DONE
Times Kalle: 12.34 10.01 -1.00
Times Anna: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34 -1.00
Times Per-Erik: 10.44 -1.00
Surname First name Club: Times
==========================================
 Nilsson Anna Glommen IK: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34
 Svensson Kalle Glommen IK: 10.01 12.34
 Jonsson Per-Erik Tuna OK: 10.44
```

When I compile and run my program my terminal will look like this:

```
Enter participants: 
Kalle Svensson Glommen IK
Anna Nilsson Glommen IK
Per-Erik Jonsson Tuna OK
DONE 
Times Kalle: 12.34 10.01 -1.00
Times Anna: 8.05 9.57 10.00 12.34 -1.00
Times Per-Erik: 10.44 -1.00
Surname   First name          Club: Times
==========================================
 Svensson     Kalle      Glommen IK 12.34 10.01
  Nilsson      Anna      Glommen IK 8.05 9.57 10 12.34
  Jonsson  Per-Erik         Tuna OK 10.44
```

As you can see, it should sort the runners by their times. The runner with the best time should be placed first and all of his times should be placed in order. This doesn't happen here and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Runner_Type {
  string first_name;
  string surname;
  string club;
  string club_last;
  vector<double> time; 
};

using Many_Runners_Type = vector<Runner_Type>;

void print(Runner_Type const & runner) {
  cout << setw(9) << runner.surname << setw(10) << runner.first_name << setw(13) << runner.club << setw(3) << runner.club_last;

  for (double const tid : runner.time) {
    cout << ' ' << tid;
  }
}

void print(Many_Runners_Type const & many_runners) {
  for (Runner_Type const & runner : many_runners) {      
    print(runner);
    cout << endl;
  }
}

bool operator<(Runner_Type const & lhs, Runner_Type const & rhs) {
  for (int j {}; j < static_cast<int>(lhs.time.size()); ++j) {
    if (lhs.time.at(j) < rhs.time.at(j)) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (lhs.time.at(j) > rhs.time.at(j)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

int main() {
  Runner_Type runner {};
  Many_Runners_Type many_runners {};
  string name {};
  double tid {};

  cout << "Enter participants: " << endl;

  while (true) {
    cin >> name;

    if (name == "DONE") {
      break;
    }

    runner.first_name = name;

    cin >> runner.surname >> runner.club >> runner.club_last;
    many_runners.push_back(runner);
  }

  for (size_t i {}; i < many_runners.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Times " << many_runners.at(i).first_name << ": ";

    while (cin >> tid && tid != -1.0) {
      many_runners[i].time.push_back(tid);
    }
  }
  
  cout << "Surname" << setw(11) << "First name" << setw(23) << "Club: Times" << endl;
  cout << "==========================================" << endl;

  // sort(begin(many_runners), end(many_runners));
  sort(begin(runner.time), end(runner.time));
  print(many_runners);
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I believe it's a minor fix, but I can't seem to solve it. When I try do `sort(begin(runner.time), end(runner.time));` in my for loop in the `void print(Many_Runners_Type const & many_runners)`subprogram I get a huge amount of pages containing numerous error messages.

So my question is; how can I sort my runner times so that it fulfills the given requirements? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [example]? There's a lot here that's just noise and it's hard for some people (me) to read through. Off the top of my head, your comparison operator probably doesn't impose a strict weak ordering.

Comment: The canonical answer to the question in the titile is: `std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end())`

Comment: I see you are using `std::cin >> some_variable; use(some_variable);`: you need to **always** check *after* attempting to read, if the read operation was successful! Not checking for successful input a huge source of errors.

Comment: You can rewrite your comparison function to just `return lhs.time < rhs.time` since `vector` is already sorted lexicographically.

Comment: @DietmarKühl in this case you also need to provide a comparison function to `std::sort`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl it's valid to shift the responsibility for input to the user, especially for school problems. You don't always need to check.

Comment: @JohnFilleau: I disagree as I see this incorrect code always even in professional code! That is, correct reading of input needs to be taught right from the start.

Comment: Your comparison function doesn't define a [strict weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). Trying to sort based on a comparison function which doesn't yield a strict weak order will produce random results. You comparison function is also overly complicated. Do this instead: find the first position where values differ (either because there are values and they differ or because one range doesn't have values) and return `true` if the value for the first argument is smaller. I haven't tried it but I'd guess that is your actual problem.

Comment: you store the times of 1 runner but you have more than 1. Not only because of that, its a little strange that you have `Runner_Type runner {};` and `Many_Runners_Type many_runners {};`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: right - the code sorts one `vector<double>`. Still, the `operator<()` doesn't define a strict weak order although it better does. Indeed, the code _should_ sort all the times for each runner and, finally, sort the runners based on the [currently unused] `operator<`.

Comment: *"When I try [sorting] I get a huge amount of pages containing numerous error messages."* -- focus on the first error and ignore the rest. Often a single typo can cause a compiler to report multiple errors. (From personal experience, I had a forgotten semicolon result in around 40 or 50 errors reported.) Focus on the code that triggers that first error.

Comment: To help you focus, and to make it easier on those volunteering to help you, you should reduce your code to a [mre]. Drop the requirements of your assignment and focus on your error. (Make a copy of your code and work in that.) For example, you are focused on sorting your data. That's good, but make your code match. Instead of asking for user input, just hardcode data into your code. That first loop in your `main` function could be more like `many_runners.emplace_back("Kalle", "Svensson"); many_runners.emplace_back("Anna", "Nilsson");` (or something like that -- comments are limited length).

Comment: That first error is probably complaining that you are trying to sort a `Runner_Type const&`. The `const` means "may not be changed".

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting only the `time` vector of the *last* `runner` entered by the user (you made a similar mistake in the code of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455632/), where you were pushing everyone's `time` values only into the last `runner` entered).

You need to add a call to `sort()` after the loop that populates `many_runners[i].time` is finished, so that you are sorting the `time` vector of *every* runner, eg:

```cpp
for (size_t i {}; i < many_runners.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Times " << many_runners[i].first_name << ": ";

    while (cin >> tid && tid != -1.0) {
        many_runners[i].time.push_back(tid);
    }

    sort(begin(many_runners[i].time), end(many_runners[i].time)); // <-- ADD THIS
}
```

With each runner's `time`s now sorted from fastest to slowest, each runner's *fastest* time is stored in `time[0]` so that is the only vector value your `operator<` needs to compare, not the entire vector, eg:

```cpp
bool operator<(Runner_Type const & lhs, Runner_Type const & rhs) {
    if (!lhs.time.empty()) {
        return rhs.time.empty()  || lhs.time[0] < rhs.time[0];
    }
    else {
        return rhs.time.empty();
    }
}
```

Then lastly, the final call to `sort()` before `print()` needs to be changed to sort the `many_runners` vector (like I already showed you in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455875/65863) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455632/)), not the `time` vector of the last `runner`:

```cpp
sort(begin(many_runners), end(many_runners)); // <--
print(many_runners);
```

Comment: Best time means the least amount of time. As you can see in the example the runner with the best time should be placed first and his/hers times should be placed in an ascending order starting from lowest to highest. How do I do this?

Comment: So if a runner has 12,35s, 45,23s and 11.23s. The best time will be 11.23s

Comment: The thing about this is that all the runners time ALSO needs to be in ascending order so if Charles inputs the following times: 12.23 5.23 15.12 -1.00, it needs to be: 5.23 12.23 15.12. Look at the example of how it should look in the terminal

Comment: @Cebu Sorting an individual runner's times is easy. That is not an issue. I'm questioning how you want to sort the order of the runners in relation to each other. You say "*the runner with the best time should be placed first*" but what does that mean exactly? How is Anna's 4 times considered "better" than Kalle's 2 times or Erik's 1 time? What is the criteria you are using to determine "better"? That is what you have not clearly defined yet, in either this question or your previous question. Please do so.

Comment: The program should finally print all runners sorted according to the runners' individual fastest time
(the runner with the fastest time is printed first, followed by the runner with the second fastest time, ect.). Also
the runners' own times must be printed sorted where the fastest time is printed first, followed by the second fastest
time, ect. The times must be printed separated by exactly one space.

Comment: I am going to add this explaination to my question and I really hope you can assist me with this if you want. Feel free to tell me if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: @Cebu that is exactly what I was looking for. I have updated both of my answers.